# Linq XML complex select (3 levels)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to get the exact parameter `ConnectionString` from the `MAINDB` config section from `ServerConfig`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ServerConfig>
  <config section="MAINDB">
    <parameter type="ConnectionString">"CONNSTRING"</parameter>
    <parameter type="ConnectionString1">"CONNSTRING1"</parameter>
    <parameter type="ConnectionString2">"CONNSTRING2"</parameter>
    <parameter type="ConnectionString3">"CONNSTRING3"</parameter>
  </config>
  <config section="OTHERDB">
    <parameter type="ConnectionString">"CONNSTRING"</parameter>
    <parameter type="ConnectionString1">"CONNSTRING1"</parameter>
    <parameter type="ConnectionString2">"CONNSTRING2"</parameter>
    <parameter type="ConnectionString3">"CONNSTRING3"</parameter>
  </config>
  <config section="OTHERPARAM">
    <parameter type="OtherString">"OTHERSTRING"</parameter>
  </config>
</ServerConfig>
```

I have tried several approaches with Linq with no success.

My last try:

```cs
var parameters =
    from el in xdoc.Elements(GivenSystem)
    where (from add in el.Elements("config")
          where (string)add.Attribute("section") == ConfigSection
          select add).Any()
    select el;

foreach (var t in parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Value.ToString() + " - ");
}
```

selects all the parameters from all sections.

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1):

It's situations like this here using xpath is a lot cleaner.  LINQ to XML queries can get a bit lengthy.

```
const string configSection = "MAINDB";
const string parameterType = "ConnectionString";

// using xpath //
var xpath = String.Format(
    "/ServerConfig/config[@section='{0}']/parameter[@type='{1}']",
    configSection, parameterType
);
var query1 = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);

// using LINQ //
var query2 =
    (from config in doc.Elements("ServerConfig").Elements("config")
    where (string)config.Attribute("section") == configSection
    from parameter in config.Elements("parameter")
    where (string)parameter.Attribute("type") == parameterType
    select (string)parameter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var connectionString = (from c in xdoc.Root.Elements("config")
                        where (string) c.Attribute("section") == "MAINDB"
                        from p in c.Elements("parameter")
                        where (string) p.Attribute("type") == "ConnectionString"
                        select (string) p).FirstOrDefault();
```

`connectionString` will contain your value or will be `null` when it's not found.